# How to show image in react using the data from mysql created by xampp

Tags: mysql, reactjs, xampp

I have used nodejs and xampp to create a server. In Xampp for the image, i have used Blob long. Using react as frontend, I fetched the image. I assigned this img data to the image src but its not displaying. Inspect on the image src, show a long series of numbers.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function QueryData() {
  const [backenddata, setBackenddata] = useState([]);

  async function fetchData(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const result = await response.json()
    setBackenddata(result);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let url = "http://localhost:3001/"; //xampp server
    fetchData(url);
  }, []);
    
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={backenddata[0]?.ProductImage.data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the image was not showing because the encoded base64 was incorrect. You could verify your base64 result data by comparing with the data from http://jpillora.com/base64-encoder/

Initially i used this method to convert to bass64

```
var blob = new Blob(backenddata[0]?.ProductImage.data, {
  type: "image/jpeg",
});
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
reader.onloadend = function () {
  let base64String = reader.result;
  setImagesrc(base64String); //assigned to state. This base64 value was wrong compared to data from http://jpillora.com/base64-encoder/
};
```

So i have changed to below code and it was correct and same as the http://jpillora.com/base64-encoder/

```
  var base64String = btoa(
    String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(backenddata[0]?.ProductImage.data))
  );
  setImagesrc(base64String);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using blob you need to convert you data to base64 by using the following code, then use can use Base64 in your img tag src

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function QueryData() {
  const [backenddata, setBackenddata] = useState([]);

  async function fetchData(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const result = await response.json()
    // result.data should be as arrayBuffer type
    let base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(result.data)));
    setBackenddata(base64String);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let url = "http://localhost:3001/"; //xampp server
    fetchData(url);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={backenddata} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

this is an example of arrayBuffer looks like
[image]

Comment: Hey tito, thanks for the response.
I managed to convert it to base64

Comment: now the image src is <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,somecharacters"

however, the image is not showing

Comment: can you share the response of API?